# PhP echo a table value from SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have a registration system, with a dashboard. I have a My Profile tab, and there a table with 4 columns,
USERNAME,Email,Credit,Joindate.

The Problem is that i don't know how to echo the value from the credit table!

There are my code:

```
<?php 
    $page_title = "Profile";
    include_once 'includes/header.php';
    include_once 'controllers/ParseProfile.php';
?>

<div class="container">
    <div>
        <h1>Profile</h1>
        <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>

            <p class="lead">
                Your not authorised to view this page <a href="login.php">Login</a> Not yet a member? <a href="register.php">Register</a>
            </p>
        <?php else : ?>
            <section class="col-lg-7">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                    <tr><th>Username:</th><td><?php if(isset($username)) echo $username; ?></td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Email: </th><td><?php if(isset($email)) echo $email; ?></td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Earned Money: </th><td><?php if(isset($credit)) echo $credit ?></td></tr>
                    <tr><th>Date Joined: </th><td><?php if(isset($date_joined)) echo $date_joined; ?></td></tr>
                    <tr><th></th><td><a class="pull-right" href="edit-profile.php?user_identity=<?php if(isset($encode_id)) echo $encode_id; ?>">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>Edit Profile</a></td></tr>
                </table>
            </section>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>


<?php include_once'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

And the SQL COMMANDS in this php file: [NOT ALL OF THEM, JUST WHAT NEED]

```
<?php 
    include_once'config/Database.php';
    include_once'config/Utilities.php';

    if((isset($_SESSION['id']) || isset($_GET['user_identity'])) && !isset($_POST['updateProfileBtn'])){
        if(isset($_GET['user_identity'])){
            $url_encode_id = $_GET['user_identity'];
            $decode_id = base64_decode($url_encode_id);
            $user_id_array = explode("encodeuserid", $decode_id);
            $id = $user_id_array[1];
        }
        else {
            $id = $_SESSION['id'];
        }

        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id";
        $statement = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $statement->execute(array(':id' => $id));

        while($rs = $statement->fetch()){
            $username = $rs['username']; 
            $email = $rs['email'];
            $credit = $rs['credit'];
            $date_joined = strftime("%d %b %Y", strtotime($rs["join_date"]));
        }

        $encode_id = base64_encode("encodeuserid{$id}");
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['updateProfileBtn'])) {
        //Initilaise the array
        $form_errors = array();

        //form validation
        $required_fields = array('email', 'username');

        //check empty fields and merge into array
        $form_errors = array_merge($form_errors, check_empty_fields($required_fields));

        //fields to check length
        $fields_to_check_length = array('username' => 4);

        //check min length and put data in array
        $form_errors = array_merge($form_errors, check_min_length($fields_to_check_length));

        //Email validation
        $form_errors = array_merge($form_errors, check_email($_POST));

        //Collect data from form
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $hidden_id = $_POST['hidden_id'];

        if(empty($form_errors)){
            try{
                //create sql update
                $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE users SET username =:username, email =:email WHERE id =:id";

                //Sanitise 
                $statement = $db->prepare($sqlUpdate);

                //update 
                $statement->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':email' => $email, ':id' => $hidden_id));

                //Check if one new row was created
                if($statement->rowCount() == 1){
                    $result = '
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            swal("Updated!", "Profile update successful", "success");
                        </script>
                    ';
                }
                else {
                    $result = '
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            swal("Nothing Happened", "You didnt make any changes");
                        </script>
                    ';
                }
            }
            catch (PDOException $ex) {
                $result = flashMessage("An error occured in: " .$ex->getMessage());
            }
        }
        else {
            if(count($form_errors) == 1) {
                $result = flashMessage("There was 1 error in the form <br>");
            }
            else {
                $result = flashMessage("There were " .count($form_errors). " errors in the form <br>");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are `$db` and `$id` defined? And when you say _" i don't know how to echo the value"_, what exactly do you mean? What happens? From what I can see, you do know how to echo values since you're doing it in the code so we need more info about the actual issue here

Comment: i told u i don t copy all of the code. I have the $id valid. It's working, i get specified variable for username for email to, just for credit i get nothing.

Comment: I also don't see the point to base64 encode the id.

Comment: So do a `var_dump($rs)` inside the loop and check what it actually contains. It's literally impossible for us to know what's going on when we only can see parts of the code and without any insight into what the database actually contains.

Comment: i edited the question! i put the full code.